# Entity Framework. Как определить, выполнился ли запрос

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Например у меня есть код:

```
await _entities.AddAsync(entity);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Где _entities - DbSet, _db - DbContext, entity - добавляемый объект. Как узнать добавлена ли запись в бд?

Проверку нужно сделать во время исполнения программы.

Единственное, что пришло в голову это сделать так:

```
    public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return false;

        try
        {
            await _entities.AddAsync(entity);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: вам из кода нужно ?

Comment: да, нужно сделать проверку во время исполнения программы

Comment: можно просто проверить запросом существование вашей записи по её имени (ключу) после добавления. Имя уже известно  при добавлении

Comment: мне кажется это крайне не оптимальное решение, придется при каждом внесении изменения в базу данных проверять выполнились ли эти изменения.

Comment: Не помню, как в `EntityFramework`, но в других ORM-решениях методы вставки или сохранения возвращают статус код операции.

Comment: Решение с try-catch нормальное. Если не получится сохранить сущность, будет исключение.

Comment: try-catch, насколько я знаю, сильно влияет на производительность и использовать его без обработки дурной тон. Или если исключение не возникает влияние минимально? Я просто плохо знаю как работают исключения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Результат выполнения метода  [SaveChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn220070(v=vs.113).aspx) возвращает количество объектов, записанных в базу данных.

Поэтому можно сделать так:

```
var count = await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
if(count == 1)//в вашей ситуации вы записываете 1 обьект
{
    //значит обьект был сохранен в базу
}
```